# using gmap3 to get location and plot route to known location - needs some fine tuning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

i'm trying to use gmap3 to do the above but am running into difficulty. i can get 'map' to display and stick a marker on it. i'm still getting to grips with javascript and i'm sure some of my syntax is off which obviously doesn't help.

am i on the right track with regards to using geolocation to get the user's location and then plot the route to a predefined location?

apologies for incorrect syntax - i'm finding it hard to keep track brackets when using JS.

i'm using the example which can be found here: http://gmap3.net/api/add-directions-renderer.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () {
        //get the user's location
        function getLocation(){
            $('#map').gmap3({ 
              action : 'geoLatLng',
              callback : function(latLng){
                if (latLng){
                  $(this).gmap3({
                    action: 'addMarker', 
                    latLng:latLng
                  },
                  "autofit");
                } 
              }
            });
        }
        //plot directions
        function plotRoute() {
          $('#map').gmap3({
            action: 'getRoute',
            options:{
              origin: 'latLang',
              destination: 'Tallaght Business Park, Dublin, Ireland'
              travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            },
            callback: function(results){
              if (!results) return;
              $(this).gmap3({
                action: 'init',
                zoom: 13,
                mapTyprId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                streetViewControl: true
              },
              action: 'addDirectionsRenderer',
              options: {
                preserveViewPort: true,
                draggable: true,
                directions: results
              }
              );
            }
          });
        }
      });
    </script>
```

to be placed in this div

```
<div class="gmap3" id="map"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think this piece is correct: **origin: 'latLang',**. That would just tell Google API that you have some address called literally 'latLang', which doesn't mean anything. I'm not sure what you actually wanted to have instead. If you wanted to have user's location as an origin, you'd need to get latlng from previously created marker.

Comment: after changing my code slightly i reposted and got an answer which can be seen here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004744/google-maps-gmap3-plotting-a-route-to-a-known-destination-from-a-users-geoloc/12012324#12012324